# I have an issue about normal mapping

Tags: normal-map

I am trying to get an high poly model to a low poly model with the help of normal map baking. However I have an issue with it as I get a very weird map.

[Blender model](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yKf8rvbM3zsA-JHrMlI16eCpsCCjrpWR?usp=sharing).

If opening the file properly does not work, please tell me how I can share it.

I am using EXOSIDE Quad Remesher Add-on for remeshing into a low poly model

[image]

Comment: You have no ray extrusion, and your low poly doesn't enclose your high poly.  You have max ray distance (which you usually shouldn't have.)  I suspect you have, trying to accommodate earlier tutorials, mistaken ray extrusion for max ray distance.  In addition to this, your low poly is rather detailed compared to the distance from high->low, and you'll need to be using a cage (or even separation to parts) to bake this particular high->low normal map-- your low poly will self-intersect before it will enclose your high poly.

Comment: The file is 1Gb of size?